Jio Phone Prima (Feature Phone with KaiOS) is not showing in adb list devices after turning on debug mode
I turned on debug mode using code *#*#0574#*#* but when i tried adb list devices then device is not showing.
Phone Name: JioPhone Prima 4G Keypad Phone 
OS: kaiOS 2.5.3

I tried turned on debug mode using code *#*#0574#*#* but in adb list device the device is not showing.



Image 1
Image 2
Image 3











What OS do you use on the PC? Is your phone connected via USB to the PC? If you use Windows have you installed the appropriate adb driver to the correct device in Windows device manager?

I use Windows 11 Home and adb is working fine if I connect any other android phone.

KaiOS bass on the discontinued FirefoxOS. May be the recent adb version is not compatible?

I am also facing the same issue for Jio Phone Prima Model F491H. Although if you switch off the phone and then press up+power button and then release the power button you will see android robot just press power button once you will enter stock recovery. here adb detects the device but as recovery.
